# Abstract class, how to make method abstract

Tags: php, abstract-class, abstraction

few days ago i was on a job interview, i was asked a question like this one:

> There is an abstract class `A` with two methods `foo` and `bar`, from
>   it generated derived class `C`, which was implement only the method
>   `foo`. What changes need to take place in the script, in order to make
>   it work, **while the implementation and interface classes A and C
>   should not be changed**

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public function foo();
    abstract public function bar();
}

class C extends A {
    public function foo() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

i said: okay we can simple add one  method to our `C` class

```
public function bar() {
   //
}
```

they said this is ok, but what if you can't add this method and you can't change abstract class `A` (and its methods).

And there are two options, either my interviewer are fool or i am fool and missing something.

I have read `php.net` documentation about abstract classes and i do not see any other solution.(ofcourse i can make class `A` not abstract or remove `abstract modifier` from `bar` method but i am not allowed to do that);

Help me please, because this question don't let me sleep!

Comment: You're not allowed to change anything in the 2 classes then how can you fix it? Your interviewer is a tool, because above code always returns a fatal error. The only thing that comes to mind is making `C` also abstract class, but you can't do that I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to declare Class C is Abstract.

Comment: i know that, but i dont know if there any other sulution, but thank you for answer